# Basic question about Current (I) flow

Tags: current

Somewhere I've read:

> Current (I) is given by 1 Coulomb per second. One ampere of
>   current is a flow rate of 6,250,000,000,000,000,000 electrons passing a given point per
>   second.

If it is correct then my question is what is this *given point*? Like point A to point B?
Just saying, `1Amp = 1 Coulomb per second` isn't making any sense to me.

Comment: Just like you can pick a point along a river and say there is a flow of some gallons/minute, you can pick a point in a electric circuit and say there is a flow of some Coulombs/second, also know as Amperes, or Amps for short.

Comment: @clabacchio, next thing you will tell me I am pronouncing router incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

A Coulomb is a unit of electrical charge, and electrical charge is a property of electrons. So moving electrons from A to C via B means there's an electrical charge passing point B. How much charge? Well, the charge of a single electron is quite small: \$-1.6 \times 10^{-19}\$ Coulomb. That explains why there have to pass so many electrons before a full Coulomb is transferred. The speed at which this happens determines current, in Ampere.
So, by definition, if you see \$ 6.24 \times 10^{18}\$ electrons pass in 1 second you have 1A. If you see twice as many pass in 1 second, or \$ 12.48 \times 10^{18} \$ that's 2A. If only 1 electron passes your checkpoint every second you have a current of \$1.6 \times 10^{-19}\$A, or 0.16 attoAmpere (aA).

*(By the way, the number you've read as expressed here is wrong. Expressed the way you write it, with all the zeros, it suggests 19 significant digits. The real value is more like \$  6.241 509\times 10^{18} \$. Writing it this way means that these are the first 7 digits of the number, but it expressly says the following digits probably aren't zeros. It's the scientific way to express rounded numbers. Writing out all digits is only done if all digits are correct. Here you can see that there's already a discrepancy at the third digit. )*

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

The current (in Ampères) is theamount of electric charge (in Coulombs) that pass in a certain point (of a wire for instance, considering the wire as very very thin) during a second.

### Theory:

Suppose that you have an arbitrary area in the space. Then, you have a flux of charge across this area, and this by itself constitutes a current (I). Now, this current is made by moving charges, and the sum (or integral, in a continuous approximation) of their values is the current flowing across that surface.

So, yes, it's Coulomb / second.

Wiki: "The SI unit for measuring the rate of flow of electric charge is the Ampère, which is charge flowing through some surface at the rate of one coulomb per second"

**Base concepts:**

Current := flux of charge

In a formal way $$ I={dQ \over dt} $$

In fact, the law of charge conservation states that if you have a close surface, the current flowing across that surface will be the same of the variation over time of the charge inside that surface (or vice versa)

### Straight talking

Think to water flowing in a pipe (the usual example). If the volume of water (in liters or m3 as you wish) is the charge, the amount of water that flows in a section of the pipe over a certain time (let's say a second), also called flux, represent the current.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of electrons as a 'liquid' flowing through a pipe (or marbles rolling through the pipe for that matter). Now, the current is defined as the amount of charge (carried by whatever particles you like, normally electrons) that crosses a given arbitrary surface, i.e. the cross-section of a wire. Given that the charge of a single electron is \$ Q_e\approx -1.6^{-19} \mathrm{C} \$, it is necessary that \$6.25^{18}\$ marbles roll through the cross-section of the pipe each second, to have `1 A` of current. This *given point* is probably an obscure name given to the cross-section of a conductor (wire). I find this 'point' thing very inaccurate and misleading, unless it is a check-point, where the by-passing electrons are counted. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

One point would be one point on a wire ( taken as a line ).  You are standing on a river counting the boats go by in an hour.  This is the current ( boats/hr ).  Using a surface, not a point is because a wire is not a line it is 3D.  There is no point B. : "taken at A point"
Hope this non-math answer helps, math is the exact formulation of the idea.